# External manifest seems to be unrecognized by Windows

Tags: winapi, manifest, winsxs, sxs

I am using an external manifest for a very simple program I have written, `program.exe`. I have an external manifest, `program.exe.1.manifest`, in the same directory. These are the contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
    xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"
    manifestVersion="1.0"
    >
  <assemblyIdentity
      name="TestC.Testos.TestEx"
      processorArchitecture="amd64"
      type="win32"
      version="0.1.0.0"
      />
  <description>TestTool</description>
  <file
      loadFrom="%homepath%\Desktop\source\payload.dll"
      name="payload.dll"
      />
</assembly>
```

Now, the simple program simply calls `LoadLibraryW(L"payload.dll")`. The `payload.dll` is located in the `Windows` directory of the system, however, I am trying to load a version of `payload.dll` from a folder called `source` on my desktop. This works when I embed the manifest in the program directly, but does not when it is an external manifest. Why does an external manifest not work?

Comment: Your manifest filename should omit the `.1`. More important, make sure [external manifests are enabled](https://www.unixgr.com/enable-external-manifest-control-on-windows-10/). Also see [Find Out Why Your External Manifest Is Being Ignored](http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/27-csi-news-general/245-find-out-why-your-external-manifest-is-being-ignored).

Comment: @RemyLebeau That solved my problem, thanks

Comment: @ArushAgarampur You can also [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for sharing your solution which will be helpful for others are searching on similar issue.